# Is a*b < a for 0 <= b < 1 in IEEE floating point with positive a?

Tags: ieee-754

I am writing in C++, using conformant IEEE arithmetic in round-to-nearest mode.  If a is a positive short int (16 bits) and b is a float (32 bits), where 0 <= b < 1, does a*b < a always evaluate to true?

Comment: Does "positive short int" include zero ?  (according to no less an authority than http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point, signed-zeros are allowed).  If so, then a=0, b=0, a*b is not < a.

Comment: I meant 0 < a.  C++ integers do not have signed zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe. It depends on how the compiler decide to evaluate floating-point expressions (read about FLT_EVAL_METHOD, invented by C99 but now part of the C++ standard, if you want the gory details.)

As soon as `a` can be greater than 4, the product `a*b` expressed as a `float` will round up to `a` when `b` is "big enough", for example `b = 1-ε/2` (where ε is the difference between 1.0 and the next representable number, 2<sup>-23</sup>.) But if the compiler does **not** perform the rounding in the intermediate evaluation, before the comparison, then the product may be kept in some (better) internal precision where `a*b` is still different from `a`, and the comparison done on that internal precision will be always asserted. And this case is not uncommon: because of the design of the x87 coprocessor, keeping all results as 64-bit long double was typical of 32-bit x86 architecture, for example; 53-bit double would also keep all values separate, since 24+16<53.

Assuming there are no bugs in your compiler, a explicit cast to float *should* force the rounding, so `(float)a*b < a` *should* evaluate sometimes to false. Be specially cautious here, since this area is [known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27113114) to show compiler bugs, particularly since floating-point is declared "reserved to experts" and programmers are generally advised to **not** rely on details like these. You should particularly take care to **not** activate the *optimization* options (like [`/fp:fast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx)) of your compiler, which are very likely to *skip* the rounding operation to improve performances.

A safer (but still not completely safe) way to perform the test is to explicitly store the result of the multiplication into a `float` variable, like in

```
float c = a * b;
  if (c < a) call_Houston();
```

Here again, the C++ standard require explicit rounding (which is quite logical since the representation of the expression has to be stored into the 32-bit float variable.) But here again, some *clever* compilers, particularly when in optimization mode, might *guess* that the expression is reused just after, and could take the short path and reuse the in-register evaluation (which has more precision), and ruin your efforts (and left Houston unaware.) The GCC compiler used to recommend in such case to beg the compiler with code like

```
volatile float c = a * b;
  if (c < a) call_Houston();
```

and goes to [specific options like `-ffloat-store`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517588). This does not prevent loss of sanity points. BTW, recent versions of GCC are much more sane on this respect (since bug323 is fixed.)

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer.  I did not know about `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.  I am not sure that `b` can ever be "big enough".  Enumerating all cases with `b = 1.f - machine_epsilon / 2` seems to say that it is not possible for `(float)(a*b) == a`.  Please excuse the Python, but it makes it easier to be sure about the rounding.
    >>> import numpy
    >>> machine_eps = numpy.finfo(numpy.float32).eps
    >>> a = numpy.arange(1,2**16,dtype=numpy.float32)
    >>> b = numpy.float32(1.) - numpy.float32(machine_eps*0.5)
    >>> print repr(b)
    0.99999994
    >>> all(a*b < a)
    True

Comment: @JohnJumper: for exactly the same reasons as above (just replace "your compiler" with "the C compiler(s) used to compile Python and NumPy"), you cannot be sure that the test is evaluated using the float specifications.