# Shows a different result when divided by float 1 and int 1

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point

This is what I am getting and I don't get why this output is coming. when I change float to int it is giving proper output.

```
int delta=99999997/(float)1;     
cout<<delta<<endl;
```

**Output:**
100000000

[Image of ide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWD7c.png)

Comment: Please provide all your code, inputs, outputs, and errors  as text in the post.

Comment: Your number has too many digits, `float` cannot represent it exactly.

Comment: IEEE-754 single precision float can store about ~7 digits of precision so it can't represent such numbers. [Strange behavior when casting an int to float in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27113114/995714)

Answer (score 1):

When you divide an integer by a floating point number, the integer is converted to a floating-point number.

The reason for the weird result is that 99999997 cannot be represented exactly in a 32 bit floating point number with the precision used by C++’s `float` on your architecture.

Instead, when converted to a float, this number gets rounded to the next number which *is* representable. And that number … happens to be 100000000.

Comment: The `int` is converted to a `float`. This is not a promotion. Promotions never change the value.